# Making an input list for class element

Tags: python, list, class

How can I make an input list, that will consist of the class element? For better understanding:

```
class staff:
    def __init__(self, employee):
        self.employee = employee
```

I want to make a function, where the user will enter a name for employees (as much as he wants), and then it will be an element of class staff, so laterally user would enter age, gender, etc. So the main question is how to make a list, that would be consisted out of input staff members?

Comment: You want to create a list and append to it as many `Staff(employee=input())` objects as you want in a loop. Later, you can ask for age and gender if your `Staff` class has an appropriate method to do that.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) SO is not a code-writing service. What have you already tried and what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: You mean class "instance", right? Your class doesn't have elements per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Staff` class should take a list of employees, rather than a single employee, and you should build that list by repeatedly calling `input()`.

```
from typing import List


class Staff:
    def __init__(self, employees: List[str]):
        self._employees = employees


employees: List[str] = []
while True:
    employee = input("Enter a name: ")
    if not employee:
        break
    employees.append(employee)

staff = Staff(employees)
```